# CSS Loader Invalid Options options should NOT have additional properties at validateOptions with react_rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-bootstrap, webpacker, react-rails

I am currently creating a rails application with a react frontend. For that, I am using [react_rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails)
and  [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gems.

Now I have added [bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) following all the steps in the installation guide.

Now when I run rails server web packer compilation fails and I get the following error,

```
fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:21 Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: CSS Loader Invalid Options
options should NOT have additional properties
    at validateOptions (:3000/home/react-rails-demo_backup/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:32)
    at Object.loader (:3000/home/react-rails-demo_backup/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:34)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css (index.js:55)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css (bootstrap.css:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/components/Main.js (Header.js.jsx:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at webpackContext (.*$:33)
    at fromRequireContext.js:13
    at Object.getConstructor (fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:15)
    at Object.mountComponents (index.js:85)
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to resolve the above error?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer that question. Have you seen this? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/863

Comment: Yes @Matthew But I am not using a CSS-loader on my own. Bootstrap is using it internally. That's why I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: You should still be able to try some of the solutions given there. The solutions seem to be more webpack-related than related to the internals of how Bootstrap implements that. If you believe it's Bootstrap's problem, then you may want to submit a github issue with them and they may be able to point you in the right direction or fix any bugs related with their code.